# AGOL Date range filter on two fields

Tags: arcgis-online, date, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-experience-builder, dashboard

I am building a solution in AGOL (webapp, dashboard, or experience builder, but not map viewer or wab for devs) which shows events that can cover multiple days. These events are in two feature classes, one point and one line. In the attribute table these feature classes have fields for the event start dates and the event end dates.

I am looking for a way for the user to select a date range and show any events, point or line, that cover all or part of that range.

Do I have any options?

Comment: Does Time slider widget meet your needs ?

Comment: Question on data structure: Is each event a row with fields like: name, ID, start_date, end_date? Or is it more complex, with recurring events?

Comment: @Viv no, it's not precise enough with selection to cover all the ranges regularly queried and users have said that that they don't see what they expect for the date range they've selected with the slider.

Comment: @Mox each event is a single row for now, although I could see it being redesigned for recurring events in the future,

Answer (score 0):

Esri web applications are pretty limited when it comes to date filtering.  Without working on a custom solution the time slider is the only option for this.